# let! vs let and before in Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

In Rspec, let uses lazy instantiation so `let(:foo) { create(...) }` isn't initialised until something calls it. Usually this is good, because it is only used when needed and makes rspec testing times much quicker.

Occasionally however you will have a spec that needs that variable but doesn't explicitly call it. So with lazy instantiation, the spec will fail.

A solution is with a bang! `let!(:foo) { create(...) }` will force that the variable is initialised.

Some developers seem to be very against this and prefer:

`let(:foo) { create(...) }
 before do 
   foo
 end`

to force the initialisation.

Is there a reason for this? is there any difference between the two methods?

Comment: Perhaps they need variables that are defined after the first `let(:foo)` or need previous `before` blocks to execute first?

Comment: My guess is that they just don't know/remember there is a `let!` variant.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one difference: `before` blocks would compound, and you can overwrite `let!` with `let` and vice versa. I'll give you an example:

```
context do
  let!(:foo) { create(:foo) }
  let(:bar) { create(:bar) }
  before { bar }

  context do
    # if in this context you wish to switch back to "lazy" versions you can
    # do that for :foo, just do:
    let(:foo) { create(:foo) }
    # but you can't "undo" before, even if you define an empty one:
    before { }
    # it does not cancel the `before` blocks defined in higher contexts
  end
end
```

Edit: I just realized this does not really answer the question why someone would prefer `before` to `let!`. Maybe: as mentioned in comments the order is different, but if you depend on such nuance in your specs - it's already too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Many situations is a matter of style, and the developer is not full aware of main functionalities of RSpec and many times people just don't make sense. Humans are not machines, and specially under time pressure, developers do things that they wouldn't do in ideal conditions :).

But the both cases presented they are not strictly the same.
For example, if you are using `subject`, it is evaluated in a `before` hook before the `let!` initialization and not inside `it`. I didn't test, but I believe these cases should show the diffs:

```
let!(:car) { create(:car) }
let(:driver) { create(:driver) }
subject { driver.car() }

it { expect(subject).to eq car } # Fail:
```

This forces `car` being created before and being available for `subject`:

```
let(:driver) { create(:driver) }
subject { driver.car() }

before { create(:car) }

it { expect(subject).to eq car } # Success
```